# Does destroying a server mean the run is unsuccessful?

Tags: android-netrunner

Maybe I'm missing this from somewhere, but a situation came up in a recent game that I need clarification on.

- The runner plays Dirty Laundry on a remote server with no ICE and only one card installed in the server.
- The corp, before the runner can declare the run successful, rezzes that card.  That card is Jackson Howard.
- The corp trashes and removes Jackson Howard from the game, using his ability.

At this point, what happens to the run the runner was on?  The server is technically destroyed.  I get it that the runner can't access any cards at that point, since there is nothing else in the server.  But when is the server considered 'destroyed'?  Immediately after Jackson is trashed?  Or does the runner get to finish their turn, access all the cards in the server (which is 0), and consider it a successful run?  This has implications for run cards, obviously, but it also has implications for cards like John Masanori.  If John gives you a tag on your first unsuccessful run, this is an easy way to tag a runner with their own cards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the official [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=207&esem=4), page 4:

> #### Destruction of Servers
>
> [...]
>
> If there are no cards installed in or protecting a remote server, then the server immediately ceases to exist. If a server ceases to exist during a run, the run immediately ends. Unless the run has passed step 4.4 of the timing structure of a run, it is not considered to be successful or unsuccessful.

In particular, you do not gain money for [Dirty Laundry](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03052) and neither do you draw a card nor do you take a tag for [John Masanori](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/04009) as the run was neither successful nor unsuccessful. A run like this also doesn’t allow the corp to play cards like [Successful Demonstration](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03014) on his or her next turn.

Comment: Draw a card? Why would you get to draw a card to begin with?

Comment: @BlueRajaDannyPflughoeft The drawing of cards refers to John Masanori who would trigger on both successful and unsuccessful runs, but does not trigger at all when the server vanishes mid-run.