# Runs on remotes which end up empty or non-existent: successful or not?

Tags: android-netrunner

If a Runner runs on a server with one piece of ICE and a single card installed in the root, proceeds past the ICE (either by breaking it or by it not being rezzed - I don't think it matters), but then the card in the root is removed or trashed (let's say it's a Jackson for example), does that count as a successful run for the purpose of card abilities which are dependent on the Runner having made a successful or unsuccessful run the previous turn?

Does the answer change if there is no ICE on the server and so when the card in the root is removed, the server ceases to exist?

Comment: So, you could make the run even if there's nothing in the root of the server, as long as there's ice there. Servers don't go away as long as something is in OR protecting them. OTOH if there's no ice AND whatever's in the root goes away, the server ceases to exist. If you're in the middle of a run, the run ends, and neither "successful" nor "unsuccessful" triggers happen. But that's already answered at http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/does-destroying-a-server-mean-the-run-is-unsuccessful

Comment: Thanks, that seems to answer the question where there is no ICE - is it also the case that a run is neither successful nor unsuccessful if there are no cards installed in the root (but there is ICE protecting it, so the server still exists) immediately prior to step 4.4 of the timing of a run?

Comment: If there are no cards in the server, but the server has Ice, the run is still successful. You can use this server for Security Testing/Bank job/Dirty Laundry etc. *The Runner can take credits from Bank Job if he made a
successful run on an empty server* © Netrunner FAQ

Comment: Ok thanks, so a run on a server which ceases to exist before step 4.4 is neither successful nor unsuccessful, while a run on a sever with no cards in it (but one or more pieces of ICE) when step 4.4 is reached is a successful run, right?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.